# Extremely large vigrahas at home [>7 feet]

Tags: worship, puja, idols

I would like to know if it is permissible to keep a large vigraha of a deity at home, specially when it exceeds 7 feet. Is it allowed to keep such a large vigraha at home, in a special room like garbha-griha built separately on the house's plot in a separate garden-like place?

I would like to build a small temple of Venkateswara swamy at home, for which I have planned to build a separate 10*10 sqft room to house the vigraha, and leave appoximately 14 sqft space on either sides and a space of 15 sqft on the front from the nearest door - basically building a small temple on a 760 sqft to 1160 sqft space in my house [ I have planned it, not executed it - as I have an inherent desire to do so!]

Am I allowed to build so? I have also attached a plan of the proposed house.
[image]

Note : Green spaces are garden spaces and there are two private gardens near room 6 and room 10, while there is a central courtyard in the house, resembling a traditional kerala house.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: No in homes we can't keep very large idols .. I will try to find some sources for this.

Comment: @Rickross yes I understand the maximum limit that I've been suggested in south India is around 4-5 feet. But I am planning to dedicate a large section of my house in building a small temple. That is, a garbha-griha 100 sqft  surrounded by gardens on either side and then at the front as well, then followed by the rooms of my house. 

Basically, a small, separate mini temple inside my house, somewhat isolated from the rooms. Is that allowed? 

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Ok ... Then you should consult the opinions of a local priest or your family priest. He shall guide you the best.